# How to show distance below than cm use sensor TF-Luna Lidar

Tags: arduino

I want to ask about TF-Lunar Lidar, I've written code to know the distance in "cm" by reading the array data, right now I need some help about how to read the data so it can be showing below "cm", (mm or below but in decimal).

this is the code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //header file of software serial port
SoftwareSerial Serial1(2,3); //define software serial port name as Serial1 and define pin2 as RX and pin3 as TX
/* For Arduinoboards with multiple serial ports like DUEboard, interpret above two pieces of code and
directly use Serial1 serial port*/
float dist; //actual distance measurements of LiDAR
int strength; //signal strength of LiDAR
float temprature;
int check; //save check value
int i;
int uart[9]; //save data measured by LiDAR
const int HEADER=0x59; //frame header of data package
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial1.begin(115200); //set bit rate of serial port connecting LiDAR with Arduino
}
void loop() {
if (Serial1.available()) { //check if serial port has data input
if(Serial1.read() == HEADER) { //assess data package frame header 0x59
uart[0]=HEADER;
if (Serial1.read() == HEADER) { //assess data package frame header 0x59
uart[1] = HEADER;
for (i = 2; i < 9; i++) { //save data in array
uart[i] = Serial1.read();
}
check = uart[0] + uart[1] + uart[2] + uart[3] + uart[4] + uart[5] + uart[6] + uart[7];
if (uart[8] == (check & 0xff)){ //verify the received data as per protocol
dist = uart[2] + uart[3]*256; //calculate distance value
strength = uart[4] + uart[5] * 256; //calculate signal strength value
temprature = uart[6] + uart[7] *256;//calculate chip temprature
temprature = temprature/8 - 256;

Serial.print("dist = ");
Serial.print(dist);//output measure distance value of LiDAR
Serial.print('\t');
Serial.print("strength = ");
Serial.print(strength); //output signal strength value
Serial.print('\t');
Serial.print("Chip Temprature = ");
Serial.print(temprature);
Serial.print(" celcius degree"); //output chip temperature of Lidar
Serial.print('\t');
Serial.print("check");
Serial.println(check);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your code is flawed in any way, but your request is quite impossible. If my understanding is correct, the Luna's max resolution is 1 cm, so you shouldn't have any data for mm or decimals past cm. See specs as listed on dfrobot. https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1995.html